# Why does Python 2.7.3 think my .csv document is all on one line?

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, for-loop, line-endings

I'm new to programming and I encountered a problem in some of my coursework that I can't make any sense of. Consider an imaginary file called 'example.csv' with the following contents.

```
Key1,Value1
Key2,Value2
Key3,Value3
...
```

If I run the following code, it prints every line in the file followed by a single asterisk on the last line.  I expected it to print each line separated by an asterisk.

```
infile = open("example.csv", "r")
for line in infile:
    print line.strip()
    print '*'
    #row_elements = line.split(",")
    #print row_elements
```

Furthermore, if I try to split the line at each comma by removing the hashes in the above code I get the following output.

```
['Key1', 'Value1\rKey2', 'Value2\rKey3'...
```

By instead passing "\r" to the .split() method the output is slightly improved.

```
['Key1,Value1', 'Key2,Value2'...
```

I still don't understand why python thinks the entire file is all on one line in the first place.  Does anyone have insight into this?

Comment: It does not think that it is all on one live, your line endings are `\r\n` instead of `\n`.

Comment: No, his line endings are `'\r'`. Why should that be? @Jeremy, what OS are you using? What program created the CSV file?

Comment: My guess is still that it is `\r\n` because in the first output example it appears the spaces and `\n` are missing. Try opening the file in universal mode by using `open("example.csv", "rU")`

Comment: Rob, I'm running mac OS X 10.5, but I think the problem came up after I edited the csv file in Excel.  I tried running the program with an unedited version of the file and it worked as expected.  So, I'd say that Excel reformatted it when I saved.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your file is using `\r` as line separators (also known as the "CR" or "Classic Mac" newline convention). Python's `open` doesn't deal with this by default.

You can use "universal newlines" mode (`'rU'` mode in `open`) to open the file properly.

(Note that some Mac text editors still use `\r` as the line terminator, though these are thankfully much less common now than they were a few years ago.)

Comment: This was very helpful and 'rU' mode worked just fine.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Your input file is poorly formatted. On Linux, lines are separated by `'\n'`. On Windows, lines are separated by `'\r\n'`, but code in the runtime library makes the `'\r'` disappear.

In your file, the lines are separated by `'\r'`, which is not a standard in *any* modern operating system. Perhaps the program that created the file is flawed in some way.

Comment: As I mentioned in the comments on the question, the culprit was Excel for Mac 2011.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

if you're dealing with csv you should use the [`csv`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module, it takes care of most of the crap involved with processing csv input/output.

```
import csv
with open("example.csv", "rb") as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    for row in reader:
        print row # a list of items in your file
```

The [`with`](http://docs.python.org/2/whatsnew/2.6.html#pep-343-the-with-statement) statement hear will automatically close the file for you when you drop out of the statement block.

Comment: True, but it doesn't answer his question nor solve his problem. He *still* needs to open with `"U"`. Perhaps your answer would be better as a comment.